# Visual Studio 2013 to 2015 - Web API Invalid Local Hostname from android emulator

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

So I just encountered this very weird bug. I developed an entire Web API in Visual Studio 2013. All works fine. Now the API is used by an android app I develop myself, so when I want to make an update to the API, I test this locally.

Now I already know that an emulator runs on localhost, and so does the ASP.NET WebApi, so to access my local API from the emulator, I use my `ip4` address (192.168.2.3). This works fine **when running the API from Visual Studio 2013**.

However, when I run the API from **Visual Studio 2015**, it doesn't work anymore.

- Browsing to localhost:2664 works without problems, able to call all the endpoints on both vs2013 and vs2015
- In the browser browsing to `192.168.2.3:2664/v1/...` only works when running API from Visual Studio 2013.
- Using `10.0.2.2` that many suggested didn't work ether (on both).
- No changes made to the API code, I can re-run from visual studio 2013 or 2015 any time, problem stays the same.

Comment: Possibly the same issue resolved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109048/how-to-access-a-service-deployed-locally-in-iis-express-from-visual-studio-emula#_=_

Comment: Maybe, this post can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109048/how-to-access-a-service-deployed-locally-in-iis-express-from-visual-studio-emula